# Are random keywords useful as tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I often see questions tagged with seemingly random keywords that appear in the question but serve no use to me personally.

A few examples are [messagebox](/questions/tagged/messagebox), [button](/questions/tagged/button), [alert](/questions/tagged/alert), [click](/questions/tagged/click), [undo](/questions/tagged/undo) you get the point (I hope).

I mostly use tags to indicate the language and/or the technology I'm working with. Do tags like the ones above serve a use?

(This is not a burninate request, I'm genuinely asking for clarification.)

Comment: +1, I've been wondering about this too. And does every function in a language need to have corresponding tags?

Comment: Half the problem is that a lot of users think that tags *are* keywords, so they stuff the box full of the same words that are in their question title and body.  A lot of tags that are currently of questionable use would be more valuable if they weren't diluted by keyword stuffers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Random* keywords are not useful as tags. They're often just used to describe the problem using tags instead of the question itself. Some keywords are also bad as tags, because they can mean different things in different context.

In my opinion a keyword is good as a tag if there can be an expert on the keyword who can answer almost any question related to it. Hence, I consider tags such as [alert](/questions/tagged/alert) to be pretty bad. An alert can be almost anything that is shown to the user, and how the alert is done and what the alert actually is depends a lot on the website/program and even the underlying technology and language used.

**Generally, if I can imagine myself searching for questions to answer using the tag, it's a good tag.**

Comment: Excellent summation in that final paragraph. That should be *the* measure of whether tags should exist.